# Semaphore is not created properly in C

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I have the following problem. I want to make sure that semaphore was initialized properly, so I put there if, which should be true when an error occurs.

```
if ((sem_t *semaphore = sem_open("/sem1", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 1))
== SEM_FAILED) {handle error}
```

It seems that if an error occurs, it works just fine — I can handle that error. But when that condition is false, then that semaphore is not created, I recognized it, because process stops on sem_wait(semaphore). 
When I run the code without "if", it works fine, but I'm unable to detect any error.

What should I do?

Comment: "when that condition is false, then that semaphore is not created ... because process stops on `sem_wait(semaphore)`". How does a process sleeping on `sem_wait()`, as it would be expected to do, indicate that the semaphore was not created? What would you expect `sem_wait()` to do other than ... wait?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are declaring (another?) `semaphore` variable INSIDE of the `if` statement.  I assume that this compiles, and you've declared `semaphore` elsewhere.

Short answer: remove the `sem_t *` from your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a variable inside an `if`-statement.

Try this:

```
sem_t * semaphore = NULL;
if (SEM_FAILED == (semaphore = sem_open("/sem1", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 1))) 
{
  perror("sem_open() failed");
  /* handle error */
}
```

or even more clear:

```
sem_t * semaphore = sem_open("/sem1", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 1);
if (SEM_FAILED == semaphore)
{
  perror("sem_open() failed");
  /* handle error */
}
```